# assets never found with ajax request

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an ajax request which needs to access to some images. I tried a lot of things, but the images are never found.

the ajax request and the images are there :

[image]

The code is :

```
$chemin =   '../../public/photos/pseudo_produit/';  

        if (file_exists($chemin.$pseudo_produit->nom_photo_vignette)){
            exit("exists");             

        } else {
            exit('does not exists');                

        }
```

As I use laravel 4.2, I also tried with public_path() and app_path() functions. Without more success.

What are my errors?

Comment: I think you just need to change `$chemin.$pseudo_produit` to `$chemin.pseudo_produit`..

Comment: can you please post your controller code and ajax error plz

Answer (score 1):

This `$chemin.$pseudo_produit->nom_photo_vignette` won't work you can't access a varibale like that.

You can try something like this :

```
$nom_photo_vignette = 'vignette1';

$chemin = public_path() . 'photos/pseudo_produit/' . $nom_photo_vignette;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I detail here : **pseudo_produit->nom_photo_vignette** is a string. But I tried like you wrote : still the same. When I debug **public_path** : it returns an empty string. The problem comes from that. But why this empty string ? Because an ajax request ?